# How to add resteasy-guice apis to jboss

Tags: jboss, guice, resteasy

I am trying to use GUICE with resteasy as mentioned [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Guice1.html)

But the JBOSS does not have this resteasy-guice-2.2.1.GA.jar in lib. So I would like to know how to integrate this lib with jboss.

I am using jboss 7.0.